# ultra-light expand-collapse javascript solution?

Tags: javascript, toggle

How can I toggle the content div on/off when I click on the 'toggle' text?

```
<div class="toggle col">TOGGLE

  <div class="content-to-toggle">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a lighter version than this one:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.className.indexOf('toggle') !== -1)
    e.target.className = e.target.className.replace(/\bexp\b|\bcol\b/, function(m){ return m == 'col' ? 'exp' : 'col'; });
});
```

?

Comment: No idea what your function is doing without actually seeing the css as well.

Comment: if lighter means you write less code, consider including jQuery and using the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) ? Check out the demo, think it do what you asked.

Comment: css is something like `.col > .content-to-toggle{display:none;}` and `.exp > .content-to-toggle{display:block;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function has a few flaws:

1. *addEventListener* will fail in browsers like IE 8 and lower
2. `e.target` will fail in browsers like IE 8 and lower
3. `indexOf('toggle')` will match `toggle` anywhere in the class value, probablly better to use a regualr exprssion like: /(^|\s)toggle(\s|$)/
4. `replace(/\bexp\b|\bcol\b/` uses word breaks as the delimiter, but class values are separated by spaces, not word breaks (like hyphen)

Lastly, what do you mean by "ligther"? Less code? Faster? Uses fewer resources?

#### Edit

A better version of the function would use:

1. a cross-browser method of attaching the listener (there are many generic *addListener* functions around)
2. a generic method of determining if the class value should be toggled (a simple *hasClass* function)
3. a generic method of removing one class value and adding the other (simple *removeClass* and *addClass* functions)

Also there should be a fork to say what to do if the element doesn't have either of the classes—should it default to one or the other or do nothing?

So here's an example:

```
<title>Toggling Example</title>

<style type="text/css">
  .exp {background-color: #666666;}
  .col {background-color: #bbbbbb;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Generic container for utility functions
var util ={};

util.trim = function(s) {
  return s.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}

// Generic container for DOM functions
util.dom = {};

util.dom.hasClass = function(el, cName) {
    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)');
    return el && re.test(el.className);
};

util.dom.addClass = function(el, cName) {
    if (!util.dom.hasClass(el, cName)) {
        el.className = util.trim(el.className + ' ' + cName);
    }
};

util.dom.removeClass = function(el, cName) {
    if (util.dom.hasClass(el, cName)) {
        var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)','g');
        el.className = util.trim(el.className.replace(re, ''));
    }
}

// Generic container for DOM event functions
util.event = {};

util.event.addListener = function(el, evt, fn) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
  } else if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent('on' + evt, fn);
  }
}

function toggleClass(el, c0, c1) {

  // Replace c0 with c1
  if (util.dom.hasClass(el, c0)) {
    util.dom.removeClass(el, c0);
    util.dom.addClass(el, c1);

  // Replace c1 with c0
  } else if (util.dom.hasClass(el, c1)) {
    util.dom.removeClass(el, c1);
    util.dom.addClass(el, c0);

  // If doesn't have either class, add c0
  } else {
    util.dom.addClass(el, c0);
  }
}

// Is this "light" enough?
window.onload = function() {
  util.event.addListener(document.body, 'click', function(e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
    toggleClass(el, 'exp', 'col');
  });
}

</script>

<div>foo bar</div>
```

#### Edit 2

"Less code" is never a good reason to do anything, though it is a reasonable objective where it doesn't obfuscate or reduce clarity. In any case, here is a "better" version of your original:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   var el = e.target, cn = el.className;
   if(/(^|\s)toggle(\s|$)/.test(cn))
     el.className = cn.replace(/(^|\s)exp|col(\s|$)/, function(m){ return m == 'col' ? 'exp' : 'col';});
});
```

It is a bit more efficient and uses a standard delimiter for class name values.

Comment: ligher = less code. don't care about ie8 and class name matching, and there's no problem with 4. ..

Comment: There are browsers other than IE that use the MS event model. Changing `\b` to `\s` costs you nothing and means the logic matches the relevant standard.

Comment: thank you, but that js is huge :o I burrowed a few things from it though :P

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var cl = e.target.classList;
    if (cl.contains('toggle')) {
         cl.toggle("exp");
         cl.toggle("col");
    }
});
```

But it wouldn't be supported by many browsers :-(